# Save a .html file which loads a URL when you open it

Tags: html

I'm simply trying to open `google.com` via a .html file.
When I open this .html file it does not load Google.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<a href="http://www.google.com">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Google</title>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.google.com" />
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: i have a working javascript code that i paste inside console and it autofills a form 
is there any way to integrate the js code so when i open html file it will open the website and load inject that javascript code that will autofill the form

Comment: You want to load google.com and then auto-inject some javascript file? No, I've tried to do what you are saying in the past and it's not possible. However, if you are on Chrome you can use the extension Tampermonkey to do what you are talking about, but only on your local machine.

Comment: However, you could do that with Python or node.js and Selenium Webdriver.

Comment: ik able to do in python but i was trying to inject js code in a ios app which there is no documentation about ive searched all day so i thought about calling the js code from a html file and then using the html file inside the ios app webview to autofill form on a page

Comment: What is the iOS app?

Comment: Im making a app that helps buy items that sell out within 10seconds from websites when they drop I have the js thats working that finds product and autofills all info but having hard time injecting or calling that script when i hit start button heres link to the other question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55555404/autofill-javascript-not-executing-on-url-when-called

Answer (score 0):

Anchor tag acts as a hyperlink. You'll have to click on it manually or write a script that would do it for you.

If you want to open `google` directly without the user's action, you can use a meta refresh.

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4;url=https://google.com" />`

here, `4` would represent the amount of time you need before refreshing in seconds.